# BIG QUERY New Field With Percentage

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a Table (Data1) with it has the following information

[image]

The thing that I’m trying to achieve is creating a new query, that could show me all the fields but also the last field could be something like this.

[Amount(from period 1)] 2029 - [Amount(from period 2)] 1748 / [Amount(from period 2)] 1748 = 16

So the Query will show me this

[image]

I have try to use a While and a Case to make it work, as you can see, is an iteration between the previous amount and the next amount.

Maybe there are operators that could use for this task but don`t know about

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [LAG](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#lag) window function.

```sql
SELECT *, ROUND((LAG(Amount) OVER w - Amount) / Amount * 100, 0) || '%' AS percentage
  FROM Data1
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY Year, period);

+--------+------+--------+-------------+------------+
| period | Year | Amount |    Value    | percentage |
+--------+------+--------+-------------+------------+
|      1 | 2022 |   2029 | $61.720.000 |            |
|      2 | 2022 |   1748 | $54.115.000 | 16%        |
|      3 | 2022 |   2529 | $76.962.000 | -31%       |
|      4 | 2022 |   2409 | $69.705.000 | 5%         |
+--------+------+--------+-------------+------------+
```